# If statement is not working for some inputs

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I am trying to make a password checker in C#, and when I enter smaller values for the username and password, the program executes as expected, but when I enter larger values, the program doesn't do anything. The if statements are not validating for larger inputs. Here is my code:

```
Console.Write("Set a username: ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Set a password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Are you sure that you want these as your username and password? (Y/N)");
        Console.Write("Enter here: ");
        string decision = Console.ReadLine();

        if (decision == "Y" || decision == "y")
        {

            Console.Write("Enter your username: ");
            string inputUser = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
            string inputPass = Console.ReadLine();

            if (inputUser == username && inputPass == password)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Username and password match correctly! Restart the program to try again.");

            }
            else if (inputUser == username && inputPass != password || inputUser != username && inputPass == password)
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (inputUser == username && inputPass != password || inputUser != username && inputPass == password && i < 2)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Username or password don't match correctly. Please try again.");
                    Console.Write("Enter your username: ");
                    inputUser = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
                    inputPass = Console.ReadLine();

                    i++;


                    if (inputUser == username && inputPass == password)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Username and password match correctly! Restart the program to try again.");
                        break;
                    }

                    if (i >= 2)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Too many attempts. Please restart program to try again.");
                        break;

                    }

                }
            }
```

There are no error messages from visual studio, so I'm not sure what to do.
Edit:
Thanks to everyone who answered. I took all your suggestions into account and now the program works like expected. Here is the finished code if you are wondering:

```
Console.Write("Set a username: ");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Set a password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Are you sure that you want these as your username and password? (Y/N)");
            Console.Write("Enter here: ");
            string decision = Console.ReadLine();

            if (decision == "Y" || decision == "y")
            {

                Console.Write("Enter your username: ");
                string inputUser = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
                string inputPass = Console.ReadLine();

                if (inputUser == username && inputPass == password)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Username and password match correctly! Restart the program to try again.");

                }
                else
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while ((inputUser == username && inputPass != password) || (inputUser != username && inputPass == password) || (inputUser != username && inputPass != password) && i < 2)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Username and/or password don't match correctly. Please try again.");
                        Console.Write("Enter your username: ");
                        inputUser = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
                        inputPass = Console.ReadLine();

                        i++;


                        if (inputUser == username && inputPass == password)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Username and password match correctly! Restart the program to try again.");
                            break;
                        }

                        if (i >= 2)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Too many attempts. Please restart program to try again.");
                            break;

                        }

                    }
                }

        

            }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code using breakpoints? If you haven't, or you don't know what I'm talking about, drop what you're doing and go learn about breakpoints. This is one of the most elementary tools whenever you need to troubleshoot your code's behavior.

Comment: Your else if is redundant and can be abbreviated to just `else`. One thing I would say; when mixing AND and OR, always (always) use parentheses to clearly indicate to C# and to other coders who read your work, what you mean. `(name = "x" and age = 1) or job = "coder"` is very different to `name = "x" and (age = 1 or job = "coder")`

Comment: In your "else if" you seem to test for "exactly one of username and password is correct", so you miss "both password and username are incorrect". As Caius Jard said, just use "else" (remove the "if(...)")

Comment: FYI you are allowed to *answer* your own question when you found a solution. Please (also) then describe the changes instead of just a dump of the new code

Comment: Tip: in the `while` you can just check for `(inputUser != username || inputPass != password) && i < 2` ("if username and/or password are wrong ...")

Answer (score 0):

I ran this in a Net 5.0 console app, I pasted in a 600 character username and used the same for the password.
The app ran as expected with no error codes.

My suggestion is close visual studio and open it again.
If this doesn't work, copy and paste your code into a new console app project.
These solutions work for 8-% of all visual studio weirdnesses.